# Google Core Reporting API: Google Organic Search

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I'm working with the google core reporting API. What I want as a result are the visits of google organic.

My metric is `ga: visits`, my dimension is `ga:source`.

The google documentation said that you get the organic traffic by filtering with the filter `ga:medium==organic`. That works for all the organic traffic.

But I want just google organic without all the other organic search as a result. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two filters: `ga:medium==organic;ga:source==google`